# What is a distribution of random variable $\eta = F_{4}^*(3) - F_{4}^*(1)$

Tags: probability

I am preparing for a test from probability and I am completely stuck with this problem:

I have four random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and empirical distribution function:

$F_{4}^*(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{I(X_i\le t)}{4}$,

where I is identificator.

**I want to find distribution of $\eta = F_{4}^*(3) - F_{4}^*(1)$**

My attempt is:

$\eta$ = $F_{4}^{*}(3)$ - $F_{4}^{*}(1)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{I(X_i \le 3)}{4}$ - $\sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{I(X_i \le 1)}{4}$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{I(X_i \le 3) - I(X_i \le 1)}{4}$\

I denote $Y_i = I(X_i \le 3) - I(X_i \le 1)$

Identificator can acquires only values 0 and 1, and when $X_i \le 1$ is true, then $X_i \le 3$ is true. So $Y_i$ can also acquires only values 0 or 1. When $X_i \in$ [2,3], then $Y_i$ acquires value 1 with probability $\sum_{i=2}^{3} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^i}{i!}$. When $X_i \le 1$ or $X_i > 3$, the $Y_i$ acquires value 0 with probability (1-p).

Until there my arguments should be correct, but there is where I think my assumption is not correct:

Then i have:

$\eta = \sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{Y_i}{4}$

So every $Y_i$ can attribute to sum with 1 or zero. So I have $\binom{4}{k}$ options how to pick up k random variables $Y_i$, so:

$\eta$ =
[\begin{cases} 
0 & \binom{4}{0}p^0(1-p)^4 \\
1/4 & \binom{4}{1}p^1(1-p)^3 \\
2/4 & \binom{4}{2}p^2(1-p)^2 \\
3/4 & \binom{4}{3}p^3(1-p)^1 \\
4/4 & \binom{4}{4}p^4(1-p)^0
\end{cases}
]

Then I need to prove, that random variables $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ are independent. My attempt:

If $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ are independent, than $P(Y_1\cap Y_2\cap Y_3\cap Y_4)=P(Y_1)P(Y_2)P(Y_3)P(Y_4)$ has to be true.

$P(Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2, Y_3 = y_3, Y_4 = y_4)$ = $P(X_1 \in x_1, X_2 \in x_2, X_3 \in x_3, X_4 \in x_4)$=$\{$random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are independent $\}$= $P(X_1\in x_1)P(X_2\in x_2)P(X_3\in x_3)P(X_4 \in x_4)$=$\{$from distribution of $Y_i \}$=$P(Y_1=y_1)P(Y_2=y_2)P(Y_3=y_3)P(Y_4=y_4)$, where $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4 \in \{0, 1\}$ and for $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ holds:\
\
$x_i$ =
[ \begin{cases} 
[2 ,3] & y_i = 1 \\
[0, 1] \cup [3, \infty) >3 & y_i = 0 \\ 
\end{cases}
]

But I am not sure about this proof.

**My question is, what is distribution of $\eta$ and how to prove that $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ are independent?**

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done solving this question.
Note that, since $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},X_{4}$ are independent and
each $Y_{i}$ is a function of $X_{i}$, one obtains that
$Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4}$. Now, note that $4Y_1 \sim \text{Bernoulli(p)}$.
Therefore, $4(\sum_{i=1}^{4}Y_i) \sim \text{Binomial}(4,p)$.
That is, $\eta$ follows the distribution that is obtained by dividing a
$\text{Binomial}(4,p)$ by $4$. This is exactly the distribution you obtained.